# Can I call Android LockScreen function from Linux command line?

Tags: android, lockscreen

Running Android 4.0.4 on Emerson EM543 Tablet.  Could not install Google Play so had to install Android Market.  Market apparently somehow disables the Android system LockScreen.  So, now trying to get lockscreen back on boot (downloadable apps, as far as I can see, don't lock screen at system boot, which is what I want).  I got a terminal emulator and was wondering if there was a Linux command line argument I could use to start Droid lockscreen at system startup.  Any suggestions?

All the questions and solutions I have found regarding "lockscreen" deal with programmatic solutions.  I am looking for a command line argument that could be used in a startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically in android code, you can use Device Admin API's to lock screen, Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

```
devicepolicymanager.lockNow();
```

Comment: I am clearly way out of my league here, but since I don't believe I have the skills to write an app, could I use the above command in an Android manifest xml like this?: http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup